# How do I add a blank line between the footnote line and the footnotes?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

Between the footnote line and the first footnote on that page, I need to add a double-space. I've tried using the \ command, but it adds a space after the number. Does anyone know a way for me to do this?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Do you want to do this throughout your document, or just on an ad-hoc basis?

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article} and I wanna do it throughout the document.

Answer (score 12):

You can increase `\skip\footins` to make room, then redefine `\footnoterule` to put the extra space after the rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule

\addtolength{\skip\footins}{20pt}

\def\footnoterule{\vskip-20pt\oldfootnoterule \vskip20pt\relax}

\begin{document}

xxxx\footnote{aaa aa aa} xxxx\footnote{bb bb bb bb}

xxxx\footnote{cccc} xxxx\footnote{dddd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't want to change `\footskip`, but `\skip\footins`. (Add `\null\vfill` immediately after `\begin{document}` to see why.)

Comment: oops that's what I meant, thanks will fix.:-)

Comment: Doing it the first way caused the footnote line to appear in the middle of the body of text. How do I change \skip\footins ?

Comment: sorry I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: Something's still not right though. I think it's the "\addtolength{\skip\footins}20pt}" line.