# Distance between footnote and the line above it

Tags: spacing, footnotes

How can I edit the distance between footnote and the line above it?

Comment: There is a `\footnotesep` that governs the distance between the main text and the footnote, if that is what you mean.  There may be other distances too, of which I am unaware.  Use the search feature.  There are other questions that deal with `\footnotesep`.

Comment: There is a nice and simple solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59501/how-do-i-add-a-blank-line-between-the-footnote-line-and-the-footnotes?rq=1

Answer (score 13):

The bottom of the page, when there are footnotes, is regulated by the parameter `\skip\footins`; after this vertical skip, the `\footnoterule` is typeset. According to the LaTeX kernel documentation, this should occupy zero vertical space; the default definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 6010:
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high
```

so you should act on this definition for increasing the distance between the rule and the first footnote. The default is 2.6pt.

Here's a document that emulates placing some footnotes with different length: the argument to `\changefootnoterule` is the distance from the top of the rule to the first footnote (so 0.4pt more than the “real” distance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % just to have more room
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\changefootnoterule#1{%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \def\footnoterule{\kern-#1\p@\hrule \@width 2in \kern \dimexpr#1\p@-0.4\p@\relax}
  Text\footnote{This is a footnote}\lipsum[2]\par\kern\dimexpr#1\p@-3\p@\relax
  \end{minipage}\par\medskip\hrule\medskip}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}
\showthe\skip\footins
\changefootnoterule{3}% default
\changefootnoterule{4}
\changefootnoterule{6}
\changefootnoterule{8}
\changefootnoterule{10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When you've found a satisfying distance, just redefine `\footnoterule` in your document, say

```
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-8\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 7.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high
\makeatother
```

if `\changefootnoterule{8}` is what suits you. You might want to increase the value of `\skip\footins`; adding 2pt to it can be done by

```
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pt}
```

One might take a different road, by changing `\footnotesep`, but this parameter is rather the vertical distance between two consecutive footnotes.

Comment: This solution doesn't take care of Right To Left languages, like Hebrew - it returns the ruler to be from Left to Right.

Comment: @Zvika That's a very different ballgame.