# More space between main text and footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I want to add some space between text on the page and footnotes. I need to have "one missing line" above the black line of footnotes.
Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question has already been answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124547/distance-between-footnote-and-the-line-above-it. If you have problems in applying the method of the answer there, please edit your question to say what went wrong.

Comment: @cfr The question that @egreg references discusses this as well: `\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pt}` should do what you want.

Comment: @cfr The pictures refer to the first stage of the process. Once the distance is found, the `\footnoterule` command should be redefined.