# How to remove the separation line above the footnotes?

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I would like to remove, or in other situations customize, the separation line before the footnotes. At this moment I am working with \documentclass{beamer}. Solutions that are beamer-specific or class-agnostic are equally welcome.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title[Footnotes and separation lines]{Footnotes and separation lines}
\institute[]{Tex StackExchange}
\author{Xavier Stuvw}
\date{11 Sept 2018}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is the first title}
This is the first frame
\footnote{first footnote: it has a line on top}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some working code ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? -  Maybe related: [Distance between footnote and the line above it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124547/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob Done @Alephzero Part duplicate: to my understanding those answers don't say (clearly enough) how to remove the line unless the only solution is `\renewcommand\footnoterule{{\hrule height 0pt}}`

Comment: One answer in the link says *"You can redefine `\footnoterule` to do what you want.''* If you want to do nothing, just redefine it to do nothing, (which is what Mico's answer says). The only tricky thing, if you want to  *change* the thickness, is that *the complete `\footnoterule` command must not use any vertical space.* That is the reason for the kerns which "cancel out" the thickness of the rule.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this posting. It is *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting, "How can I change the footnote line (thickness, length)". The earlier posting dealt with changing the width and length of the footnote rule, but none of the answers there answer the new query directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write either

```
\let\footnoterule\relax
```

or

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
```

in the preamble.

I've tested both solutions with the `article` and `beamer` document classes. Absolutely no guarantee that either solution will work with *all* document classes...

Comment: Even more compact than `\renewcommand\footnoterule{{\hrule height 0pt}}`